# Exception thrown on assignment of an array to another array

Tags: java, android

I have a function which fetches a certain website's HTML code. Eventually that function will return the whole page as an array. I am trying to save the page in another array, but it will always throw an exception (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) for some reason.

I am not sure if I am just missing something elementary or if it's more than just that. To give you some of my code:

```
  protected String[] doInBackground(String... login)
        {
            String[] page = new String[1024];
            try {
                page = executeHttpGet(); //THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
            } catch (Exception e) {
                page[0] = "Error";
            }
            return page;
        }

public String[] executeHttpGet() throws Exception {
         URL u;
         InputStream is = null;
         DataInputStream dis;
         String s;
         int i = 0;
         String[] page = new String[1024];
         addSecurityException();
         Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(activity));
         try {
            u = new URL("https://myurl.com");
            is = u.openStream();        
            dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
            while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                if (s.toString().length() > 10)
                    {
                    page[i] = s.toString();
                    i++;
                    }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        }
         finally {
            try {
               is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {

            }
        } 
         return page;
    }
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I am not able to assign the returned array to the array in doInBackground()? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line causes the exception?  What is the stack trace given by the exception?

Comment: Your program limits the reading of the website to 1024 lines. When the 1025th line is read, the statement is ``page[1024] = s.toString()``, which is a disallowed index of your array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your catch-blocks are empty, which is a **terrible** idea, because you'll get **no** information when something goes wrong.
2. You don't need to initialize `page` on its declaraton, when you re-assign it two lines below (you'll have to change the `catch`-block to create a new array, 'though).
3. Have you checked that your URL doesn't return more than 1024 lines?
4. You don't need `s.toString()` when `s` is a `String`, because it will just return `s`.
5. When analyzing an exception, you should look at the whole stacktrace to find out where *exactly* the problem occurs.
6. When *asking* about an exception you should *post* the whole stacktrace!

When you have an unspecified number of elements `List` is a more flexible and easier-to-use alternative to arrays. Generally speaking, arrays are quite low-level and there's barely a reason to use them directly (they are very useful for *building* `List` implementations).

Comment: Hey, first of all, excuse my newbish behavior. Thanks for your help, it turns out the page I fetched was actually longer than the array, it was pretty stupid of me to not think of it on my own. Thanks for your other thoughts as well, I've made changes to my code and will keep it in mind for future projects.

Comment: @Tim: no need to appologize. Better to show it and learn than to hide it and keep those mistakes for a long time.